# Server is not connecting getting problem in react js

Tags: mysql, express, graphql, sequelize.js

Below the error is coming when I am running the setup

```
npm run setup
```

```
**Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.14.1, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.6]
Loaded configuration file "src\config\database.json".
Using environment "development".
ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! api@1.0.0 db:migrate: `sequelize db:migrate`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the api@1.0.0 db:migrate script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.**
```

This the code where the error is coming. Please help me to solve it.

database.json

```
    {
      "development": {
        "username": "root",
        "password": null,
        "database": "crate",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "dialect": "MySQL",
        "seeder Storage": "sequelize"
      },
      "production": {
        "username": "root",
        "password": null,
        "database": "crate",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "dialect": "MySQL",
        "seeder Storage": "sequelize"
      }
    }
```

I want to run this server setup in postman, so what code should I do? I am not understanding it. Please tell me.

Comment: This is a case where reading  the error message carefully will lead you to a solution. Is it possible that `ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` is somehow related to `password: null` in your source code? It's worth investigating. Most `root` accounts in MySQL actually have passwords. You should provide the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Please create a new user(with password) in mysql and then try to use it in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have either not installed a mysql database, or the user does not exist. sequelize.js is an orm, meaning that it will provide a layer for you app to communicate to the database, probably better than doing it natively. it is therefore not a database by itself, and as such you need to install either  Postgres, MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite or Microsoft SQL Server in order to use it. Futhermore, upon installation you need to setup a user (on the database), then use the created credentials in the configuration, by overwring the "username" and "password" values in the "database.json"
You can set up two different databases for different production environments, which is why you have "development" and "production" configurations.
Refer to the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/) for better understanding